# How to prevent memory leakage while converting from UIImage to CIImage

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiimage, ciimage

I am trying to convert UIImage to CIImage, but it increases the memory by 80-100 MB. Is this a memory leakage? If so, is there any possible way to reduce the memory leakage on converting UIImage to CIImage?

Here's my code:

```
extension UIImage {
  func toCIImage() -> CIImage {
    return CIImage(cgImage: self.cgImage!)
  }
}
```

Also, I am looking for a better solution that wouldn't result in a memory spike converting UIImage to CIImage.

Comment: On most devices the image data will be instantly copied to `CIImage` which means that each instance of `CIImage ` will consume a certain amount of memory. While the conversion happens and data is being copied you can expect to have both data chunks in memory at the same time, resulting in a spike. But that is not a memory a leak. What sort of behavior would you expect?

Comment: Shouldn't this memory spike go down after the conversion?

Comment: The spike should go down after any of the two images (`CI`, `UI`) are released. If images are not released then maybe there is another issue. Some potentials are: A for-loop needs internal autorelease pool; Using `UIImage(named:` caches images so you may need to use another constructor.